# 2 nic 2 gateways

Tags: networking, routing

I have a question.

I have a ubuntu server(GW0). It has 2 interfaces.

---

eth0: 10.20.26.10 - connected to router

eth1: 192.168.1.20 - connected to switch

---

eth0: 10.20.26.0/24, gw: 10.20.26.1

eth1: 192.168.1.0/24, gw: 192.168.1.254 (192.168.1.254 server placed in my network it has internet access)

---

I want to use this server(GW0) as my gateway for my 192.168.1.0/24 network to access 10.20.x.x subnets via 10.20.26.1 router and internet access from 192.168.1.254.

What i did.

1. echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
2. route add default gw 192.168.1.254

if i do like this internet works fine from my network, but can't access 10.20.x.x.

update 1:
if i use default gw 10.20.26.1.

```
  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
  iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

i can access 10.20.x.x, but not internet.

Than i try to use iproute.

```
echo 1 corp >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip route add default via 10.20.26.1 dev eth0 table corp
ip rule add from 10.20.0.0/16 table corp
```

How to make to this work to reach 10.20.x.x and internet. 
Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

you need a specific route to cover the /16

policy based routing is unnecessary.

`ip route add default via 192.168.1.254`

`ip route add 10.20.0.0/16 via 10.20.26.1`

Comment: i added ip route add default via 192.168.1.254 and ip route add 10.20.0.0/16 via 10.20.26.1. But still my network can't reach 10.20.x.x. Can you explain step by step pls. Thanks

Comment: The machines you want to reach need to know how to get traffic back to you.